# How to define and use a User-Defined Aggregate Function in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I know how to write a UDF in Spark SQL:

```
def belowThreshold(power: Int): Boolean = {
        return power < -40
      }

sqlContext.udf.register("belowThreshold", belowThreshold _)
```

Can I do something similar to define an aggregate function? How is this done?

For context, I want to run the following SQL query:

```
val aggDF = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT span, belowThreshold(opticalReceivePower), timestamp
                                    FROM ifDF
                                    WHERE opticalReceivePower IS NOT null
                                    GROUP BY span, timestamp
                                    ORDER BY span""")
```

It should return something like

`Row(span1, false, T0)`

I want the aggregate function to tell me if there's any values for `opticalReceivePower` in the groups defined by `span` and `timestamp` which are below the threshold. Do I need to write my UDAF differently to the UDF I pasted above?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899977/spark-dataframe-custom-aggregation-function-to-sum-a-column-of-vectors

Comment: Perhaps use `reduceByKey` / `foldByKey` as [recommended by zero323](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33901072/1048186)

Comment: Looking at the docs ended up helping me way more than the answers or any of the related answers https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html . The answer says Spark >= 2.3 but I had issues with it for 2.4

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### Supported methods

**Spark >= 3.0**

Scala `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` is being deprecated ([SPARK-30423](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30423) *Deprecate UserDefinedAggregateFunction*) in favor of registered `Aggregator`.

**Spark >= 2.3**

Vectorized udf (Python only):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType

from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd

df = sc.parallelize([
    ("a", 0), ("a", 1), ("b", 30), ("b", -50)
]).toDF(["group", "power"])

def below_threshold(threshold, group="group", power="power"):
    @pandas_udf("struct<group: string, below_threshold: boolean>", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def below_threshold_(df):
        df = pd.DataFrame(
           df.groupby(group).apply(lambda x: (x[power] < threshold).any()))
        df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
        return df

    return below_threshold_
```

Example usage:

```py
df.groupBy("group").apply(below_threshold(-40)).show()

## +-----+---------------+
## |group|below_threshold|
## +-----+---------------+
## |    b|           true|
## |    a|          false|
## +-----+---------------+
```

See also [Applying UDFs on GroupedData in PySpark (with functioning python example)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006395/6910411)

**Spark >= 2.0** (optionally 1.6 but with slightly different API):

It is possible to use `Aggregators` on typed `Datasets`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

class BelowThreshold[I](f: I => Boolean)  extends Aggregator[I, Boolean, Boolean]
    with Serializable {
  def zero = false
  def reduce(acc: Boolean, x: I) = acc | f(x)
  def merge(acc1: Boolean, acc2: Boolean) = acc1 | acc2
  def finish(acc: Boolean) = acc

  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Boolean] = Encoders.scalaBoolean
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Boolean] = Encoders.scalaBoolean
}

val belowThreshold = new BelowThreshold[(String, Int)](_._2 < - 40).toColumn
df.as[(String, Int)].groupByKey(_._1).agg(belowThreshold)
```

**Spark >= 1.5**:

In Spark 1.5 you can create UDAF like this although it is most likely an overkill:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

object belowThreshold extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    // Schema you get as an input
    def inputSchema = new StructType().add("power", IntegerType)
    // Schema of the row which is used for aggregation
    def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("ind", BooleanType)
    // Returned type
    def dataType = BooleanType
    // Self-explaining 
    def deterministic = true
    // zero value
    def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = buffer.update(0, false)
    // Similar to seqOp in aggregate
    def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
        if (!input.isNullAt(0))
          buffer.update(0, buffer.getBoolean(0) | input.getInt(0) < -40)
    }
    // Similar to combOp in aggregate
    def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
      buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getBoolean(0) | buffer2.getBoolean(0))    
    }
    // Called on exit to get return value
    def evaluate(buffer: Row) = buffer.getBoolean(0)
}
```

Example usage:

```
df
  .groupBy($"group")
  .agg(belowThreshold($"power").alias("belowThreshold"))
  .show

// +-----+--------------+
// |group|belowThreshold|
// +-----+--------------+
// |    a|         false|
// |    b|          true|
// +-----+--------------+
```

**Spark 1.4 workaround**:

I am not sure if I correctly understand your requirements but as far as I can tell plain old aggregation should be enough here:

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("a", 0), ("a", 1), ("b", 30), ("b", -50))).toDF("group", "power")

df
  .withColumn("belowThreshold", ($"power".lt(-40)).cast(IntegerType))
  .groupBy($"group")
  .agg(sum($"belowThreshold").notEqual(0).alias("belowThreshold"))
  .show

// +-----+--------------+
// |group|belowThreshold|
// +-----+--------------+
// |    a|         false|
// |    b|          true|
// +-----+--------------+
```

**Spark <= 1.4**:

As far I know, at this moment (Spark 1.4.1), there is no support for UDAF, other than the Hive ones. It should be possible with Spark 1.5 (see [SPARK-3947](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3947)).

### Unsupported / internal methods

Internally Spark uses a number of classes including [`ImperativeAggregates`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/489845f3a0e2a3555b96b6f3dbb984c783b20d97/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/interfaces.scala#L239) and [`DeclarativeAggregates`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/489845f3a0e2a3555b96b6f3dbb984c783b20d97/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/interfaces.scala#L342).

There are intended for internal usage and may change without further notice, so it is probably not something you want to use in your production code, but just for completeness `BelowThreshold` with `DeclarativeAggregate` could be implemented like this (tested with Spark 2.2-SNAPSHOT):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.DeclarativeAggregate
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class BelowThreshold(child: Expression, threshold: Expression) 
    extends  DeclarativeAggregate  {
  override def children: Seq[Expression] = Seq(child, threshold)

  override def nullable: Boolean = false
  override def dataType: DataType = BooleanType

  private lazy val belowThreshold = AttributeReference(
    "belowThreshold", BooleanType, nullable = false
  )()

  // Used to derive schema
  override lazy val aggBufferAttributes = belowThreshold :: Nil

  override lazy val initialValues = Seq(
    Literal(false)
  )

  override lazy val updateExpressions = Seq(Or(
    belowThreshold,
    If(IsNull(child), Literal(false), LessThan(child, threshold))
  ))

  override lazy val mergeExpressions = Seq(
    Or(belowThreshold.left, belowThreshold.right)
  )

  override lazy val evaluateExpression = belowThreshold
  override def defaultResult: Option[Literal] = Option(Literal(false))
}
```

It should be further wrapped with an equivalent of [`withAggregateFunction`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/369a148e591bb16ec7da54867610b207602cd698/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L62-L66).

Comment: As of Spark 2.0.1, ```Aggregator``` works with both ```groupBy``` and ```groupByKey``` (see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DatasetAggregatorSuite.scala). Unfortunatelly, ```Aggregator``` doesn't work on windows where you need to use ```UserDefinedAggregateFunction```.

Answer (score -1):

**To define and Use UDF in Spark(3.0+) Java:**

```
private static UDF1<Integer, Boolean> belowThreshold = (power) -> power < -40;
```

**Registering the UDF:**

```
SparkSession.builder()
.appName(appName)
.master(master)
.getOrCreate().udf().register("belowThreshold", belowThreshold, BooleanType);
```

**Using the UDF by Spark SQL:**

```
spark.sql("SELECT belowThreshold('50')");
```