# How to define a custom aggregation function to sum a column of Vectors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-ml

I have a DataFrame of two columns, `ID` of type `Int` and `Vec` of type `Vector` (`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`).

The DataFrame looks like follow:

```
ID,Vec
1,[0,0,5]
1,[4,0,1]
1,[1,2,1]
2,[7,5,0]
2,[3,3,4]
3,[0,8,1]
3,[0,0,1]
3,[7,7,7]
....
```

I would like to do a `groupBy($"ID")` then apply an aggregation on the rows inside each group by summing the vectors.

The desired output of the above example would be:

```
ID,SumOfVectors
1,[5,2,7]
2,[10,8,4]
3,[7,15,9]
...
```

The available aggregation functions will not work, e.g. `df.groupBy($"ID").agg(sum($"Vec")` will lead to an ClassCastException.

How to implement a custom aggregation function that allows me to do the sum of vectors or arrays or any other custom operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I define and use a User-Defined Aggregate Function in Spark SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100973/how-can-i-define-and-use-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-spark-sql)

Comment: If anyone is trying to do this something similar in pyspark the syntax is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354915/pyspark-aggregate-sum-vector-element-wise/54870161#54870161

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.0**

You can use `Summarizer` with `sum`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Summarizer

df
  .groupBy($"id")
  .agg(Summarizer.sum($"vec").alias("vec"))
```

**Spark <= 3.0**

Personally I wouldn't bother with UDAFs. There are more than verbose and not exactly fast ([Spark UDAF with ArrayType as bufferSchema performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293454/6910411)) Instead I would simply use `reduceByKey` / `foldByKey`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

def dv(values: Double*): Vector = Vectors.dense(values.toArray)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (1, dv(0,0,5)), (1, dv(4,0,1)), (1, dv(1,2,1)),
    (2, dv(7,5,0)), (2, dv(3,3,4)), 
    (3, dv(0,8,1)), (3, dv(0,0,1)), (3, dv(7,7,7)))
  ).toDF("id", "vec")

val aggregated = df
  .rdd
  .map{ case Row(k: Int, v: Vector) => (k, BDV(v.toDense.values)) }
  .foldByKey(BDV.zeros[Double](3))(_ += _)
  .mapValues(v => Vectors.dense(v.toArray))
  .toDF("id", "vec")

aggregated.show

// +---+--------------+
// | id|           vec|
// +---+--------------+
// |  1| [5.0,2.0,7.0]|
// |  2|[10.0,8.0,4.0]|
// |  3|[7.0,15.0,9.0]|
// +---+--------------+
```

And just for comparison a "simple" UDAF. Required imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer,
  UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors, SQLDataTypes}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, ArrayType, DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
```

Class definition:

```
class VectorSum (n: Int) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    def inputSchema = new StructType().add("v", SQLDataTypes.VectorType)
    def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("buff", ArrayType(DoubleType))
    def dataType = SQLDataTypes.VectorType
    def deterministic = true 

    def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
      buffer.update(0, Array.fill(n)(0.0))
    }

    def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
      if (!input.isNullAt(0)) {
        val buff = buffer.getAs[WrappedArray[Double]](0) 
        val v = input.getAs[Vector](0).toSparse
        for (i <- v.indices) {
          buff(i) += v(i)
        }
        buffer.update(0, buff)
      }
    }

    def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
      val buff1 = buffer1.getAs[WrappedArray[Double]](0) 
      val buff2 = buffer2.getAs[WrappedArray[Double]](0) 
      for ((x, i) <- buff2.zipWithIndex) {
        buff1(i) += x
      }
      buffer1.update(0, buff1)
    }

    def evaluate(buffer: Row) =  Vectors.dense(
      buffer.getAs[Seq[Double]](0).toArray)
}
```

And an example usage:

```
df.groupBy($"id").agg(new VectorSum(3)($"vec") alias "vec").show

// +---+--------------+
// | id|           vec|
// +---+--------------+
// |  1| [5.0,2.0,7.0]|
// |  2|[10.0,8.0,4.0]|
// |  3|[7.0,15.0,9.0]|
// +---+--------------+
```

See also: [How to find mean of grouped Vector columns in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41731865).

Comment: I see that the trick is using breeze.linalg.DensVector, why it is working and the dense vectors of mllib.linalg not?

Comment: Problem is there is no `+` method for Scala version of `mllib.linalg.Vector`.

Comment: @oluies Other than UDAF? You can deconstruct internal array, aggregate individually and then recreate. But if you ask about clean out-of-the box solution there is none I am aware of.

Comment: @zero323 I am trying this now on Sark 2.0 and i am passing the vectors to a normalizer without success i am getting: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector is there any update on that for spark 2.0?

Comment: @Rami You'll need `o.a.s.ml.linalg` imports.

Comment: Thanks @zero323,  the SQLDataTypes.VectorType is the trick, i wasn't able to import the VectorUDT

Comment: Is there an alternative that lets me avoid passing the vector size (n: Int)?

Comment: @Gevorg If you prefer working with `nulls` you could initialize with `null` and set array only once you see first not null entry. I am not fond of this solution thought, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following (works on Spark 2.0.2 onward), it might be optimized but it's very nice, one thing you have to know in advance is the vector size when you create the UDAF instance

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.WeightedSparseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

class VectorAggregate(val numFeatures: Int)
   extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

private type B = Map[Int, Double]

def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("vec", new VectorUDT()) :: Nil)

def bufferSchema: StructType =
StructType(StructField("agg", MapType(IntegerType, DoubleType)) :: Nil)

def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit =
buffer.update(0, Map.empty[Int, Double])

def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val zero = buffer.getAs[B](0)
    input match {
        case Row(DenseVector(values)) => buffer.update(0, values.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(zero){case (acc,(v,i)) => acc.updated(i, v + acc.getOrElse(i,0d))})
        case Row(SparseVector(_, indices, values)) => buffer.update(0, values.zip(indices).foldLeft(zero){case (acc,(v,i)) => acc.updated(i, v + acc.getOrElse(i,0d))}) }}
def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
val zero = buffer1.getAs[B](0)
buffer1.update(0, buffer2.getAs[B](0).foldLeft(zero){case (acc,(i,v)) => acc.updated(i, v + acc.getOrElse(i,0d))})}

def deterministic: Boolean = true

def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    val Row(agg: B) = buffer
    val indices = agg.keys.toArray.sorted
    Vectors.sparse(numFeatures,indices,indices.map(agg)).compressed
}

def dataType: DataType = new VectorUDT()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With **pyspark** 3.0.0, which is my version, you can use Summarizer to do it easily. Your col needs to be type of *DenseVector*

```
from pyspark.ml.stat import Summarizer
sdf.groupBy("ID").agg(Summarizer.mean(sdf.Vec)).show()
```

Note: there is no *avg* function in pyspark, but you can use *mean* method