# PySpark - undefined function collect_list

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Python 2.6.6 and Spark 1.6.0. I have `df` like this:

```
id | name      |  number |
-------------------------- 
1  | joe       | 148590  |
2  | bob       | 148590  |
2  | steve     | 279109  |
3  | sue       | 382901  |
3  | linda     | 148590  |
```

Whenever I try to run something like
`df2 = df.groupBy('id','length','type').pivot('id').agg(collect_list('name'))`, I get the following error
`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'undefined function collect_list;'` Why is this?

I have also tried:
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
`df2 = df.groupBy('id','length','type').pivot('id').agg(hive_context.collect_list('name'))` and get the error:

`AttributeError: 'HiveContext' object has no attribute 'collect_list'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `collect_list` looks like a user-defined function. PySpark API only supports a handful of predefined functions like sum, count etc

If you are referring to any other code, please ensure you have the collect_list function defined somewhere.
To import the collectivist function add below line in the top

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

And then change your code as:

```
 df.groupBy('id','length','type').pivot('id').agg(F.collect_list(name))
```

If you have it already defined, try below snippet.

```
df.groupBy('id','length','type').pivot('id').agg({'name':'collect_list'})
```

Comment: How to you define it? I don't think mine is.

Comment: check my updated answer. Here is the useful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026178/custom-aggregation-on-pyspark-dataframes

Comment: I get the error: `Aggregate expression required for pivot, found 'pythonUDF#33';`

Comment: that seems to be a different error. Which also means your collecti_list related errors solved. 
For the new error, I believe you need to change the order of agg and pivot.
df.groupBy('id','length','type').agg({'name':'collect_list'}).pivot('id')

Comment: Also, can you mark this question as answered since it only regards to collect_list

Comment: Marked as answered. But when I try what you suggested: `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"expression 'pythonUDF' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;"`

Comment: Ok.. looks like pivot should be first. So that is not the issue. Maybe you can post a new question with this pivot related error.

Comment: thanks. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684123/pyspark-aggregate-expression-required-for-pivot-found-pythonudf