# PySpark - Aggregate expression required for pivot, found 'pythonUDF'

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Python 2.6.6 and Spark 1.6.0. I have df like this:

```
id | name      |  number |
-------------------------- 
1  | joe       | 148590  |
2  | bob       | 148590  |
2  | steve     | 279109  |
3  | sue       | 382901  |
3  | linda     | 148590  |
```

Whenever I try to run something like
`df2 = df.groupBy('id','length','type').pivot('id').agg(F.collect_list('name'))`,
I get the following error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Aggregate expression required for pivot, found 'pythonUDF#93';"`
Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I used SQLContext to create the original data frame. Changed to HiveContext.