# How do I aggregate array elements column-wise in pyspark?

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| [1,2,3,4] | [0,1,0,3] |
| [5,6,7,8] | [0,3,4,8] |

`desired result:`

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| [6,8,10,12] | [0,4,4,11] |

In snowflake's snowpark this is relatively straight forward using [array_construct](https://docs.snowflake.com/ko/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.array_construct.html). Apache Spark has a similar [array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html) function but there is a major difference.

In snowpark, I can do `array_construct(count('*'), sum(col('x')), sum(col('y'), count(col('y')))` but apache spark seems to count `array()` as an aggregation and complains that I can't have an aggregation inside of an aggregation.

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.;`

I'm trying to write a piece of code that can handle both snowpark and apache spark but this `array_construct` vs `array` is proving trickier than anticipated.  Next up is to explore doing a groupby & collect_list but wondering how others have solved this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark - aggregate (sum) vector element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354915/pyspark-aggregate-sum-vector-element-wise)

Answer (score 1):

If you treat the aggregations as delimited strings, you can split them to an array

```
select a, split(concat_ws(',',count(b),sum(c)),',')
from t
group by a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not the difference between array functions at all, it was a completely different issue.

I have a translation function, that translates snowpark's `regexp_count` function to pyspark using the formula

```
    def regexp_count(self, col, regex):
        return F.sum(F.when(col.rlike(regex), 1).otherwise(0))
```

This causes issues later on when I did F.sum(regexp_count(col, regex)) hence the error, because as becomes obvious, there is an `F.sum` inside an `F.sum` :/

Instead, the following translation fixes the issue

```
    def regexp_count(self, col, regex):
        return F.size(F.split(col, regex)) - 1
```