# How to apply User Defined Function on each subset formed by a Group By Operation in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    [ID_number,cust_number,feature1,feature2,feature3,....]
```

Now I want to write a query that groups by *ID_number* and applies a User Defined Function  on the subsets

```
    [cust_number,feature1,feature2,feature3,......]
```

grouped by each *ID_number*
I need to apply Machine Learning algorithms on the features and store the weights somehow.

How do I do this using Apache Spark DataFrames(Using Scala) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I define and use a User-Defined Aggregate Function in Spark SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100973/how-can-i-define-and-use-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-spark-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (pyspark).

schema_string = "cust_number,feature1,feature2,feature3"

fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in          schema_string.split(",")]

schema = StructType(fields)
df = sql_context.createDataFrame(group_by_result_rdd, schema);

Note :  here I am assuming all your features are of type String.
Look at API docs for other data types