# Applying User Function to Entire Spark DataFrame column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark DataFrame schema:

```
In [177]: testtbl.printSchema()
root
 |-- Date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Close: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Volume: double (nullable = true)
```

I wish to apply a scalar-valued function a column of `testtbl`. Suppose I wish to calculate an average of the 'Close' column. For an rdd I would do something like

```
rdd.fold(0, lambda x,y: x+y)
```

But `testtbl.Close` is not an rdd,, it is a column object with limited functionality. Rows of `testtbl` are rdds, columns are not. So how to apply `add`, or a user function to a single column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a function to an entire column, you just have to execute an aggregation operation to the column.

For instance imagine that you want to compute the `sum` of all values in the column `values`. Even though, `df` is not aggregated data, it is valid to apply aggregated functions to `DataFrames`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = sc.parallelize([(1,), (2,), (3,)]).toDF(["values"])
df.agg(sum("values").alias("sum")).show()

+---+
|sum|
+---+
|  6|
+---+
```

You can find another example in [Pyspark's aggregation documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg).

For the second part of your question. You can create a [User Defined Aggregated Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100973/how-can-i-define-and-use-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-spark-sql), but if I'm right it is only applicable for `Scala`.

Comment: Ok - `agg` is shorthand for `df.groupBy.agg()', but `agg` only supports 5 or so functions according to the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData). I'd like to apply a udf to a column (2nd part of question).

Comment: `my_user_fn(testtbl.rdd.map(lambda row: row.Close).collect())` ?, but that is inefficient and doesn't return a df.

Comment: Yes - udf's applyinng row-wise are standard, I am looking for a udaf. Looks like it is only avail in Scala. Thx.