# Calculating Weighted Mean in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to calculate weighted mean in pyspark but not making a lot of progress

```
# Example data
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("a", 7, 1), ("a", 5, 2), ("a", 4, 3),
    ("b", 2, 2), ("b", 5, 4), ("c", 1, -1)
]).toDF(["k", "v1", "v2"])
df.show()

import numpy as np
def weighted_mean(workclass, final_weight):
    return np.average(workclass, weights=final_weight)

weighted_mean_udaf = pyspark.sql.functions.udf(weighted_mean,
    pyspark.sql.types.IntegerType())
```

but when I try to execute this code

```
df.groupby('k').agg(weighted_mean_udaf(df.v1,df.v2)).show()
```

I am getting the error

```
u"expression 'pythonUDF' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get
```

My question is, can I specify a custom function ( taking multiple arguments) as argument to agg? If not, is there any alternative to perform operations like weighted mean after grouping by a key?

Comment: Did you mean to override the `weighted_mean` function?

Comment: What I want to do is a) groupby b) perform an operation depending on multiple columns of the dataframe . Weighted mean is just an example.

Comment: I think what @cricket_007 meant is do you intentionally override `weighted_mean` by this line `weighted_mean = pyspark.sql.functions.udf(weighted_mean,` or it is a typo?

Comment: I don't think that the [`agg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg) function takes that parameter type that you are giving

Comment: @cricket_007 is right here. Agg accepts only proper UDAFs. Take a look for example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32101530/1560062. There is no Python API though. For trivial cases like this one all you need is just a simple formula so it looks like a quite artificial problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A User Defined *Aggregation* Function (UDAF, which works on `pyspark.sql.GroupedData` but not supported in pyspark) is not the same as a User Defined Function  (UDF, which works on `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`).

Because in pyspark you cannot create your own UDAF, and the supplied UDAFs cannot resolve your issue, you may need to go back to RDD world:

```
from numpy import sum

def weighted_mean(vals):
    vals = list(vals)  # save the values from the iterator
    sum_of_weights = sum(tup[1] for tup in vals)
    return sum(1. * tup[0] * tup[1] / sum_of_weights for tup in vals)

df.rdd.map(
    lambda x: (x[0], tuple(x[1:]))  # reshape to (key, val) so grouping could work
).groupByKey().mapValues(
    weighted_mean
).collect()
```

Comment: Thanks @ijoseph for pointing out `map` works on `df.rdd`. At the time of writing I was used to just call `df.map` as a shorthand. Not sure if it still works, but good to be explicit.

Comment: It threw an error for me (in Spark 2.4.3) without the `.rdd`, I believe.