# Dataset.groupByKey + untyped aggregation functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have types like these:

```
case class SomeType(id: String, x: Int, y: Int, payload: String)
case class Key(x: Int, y: Int)
```

Then suppose I did `groupByKey` on a `Dataset[SomeType]` like this:

```
val input: Dataset[SomeType] = ...

val grouped: KeyValueGroupedDataset[Key, SomeType] =
  input.groupByKey(s => Key(s.x, s.y))
```

Then suppose I have a function which determines which field I want to use in an aggregation:

```
val chooseDistinguisher: SomeType => String = _.id
```

And now I would like to run an aggregation function over the grouped dataset, for example, `functions.countDistinct`, using the field obtained by the function:

```
grouped.agg(
  countDistinct(<something which depends on chooseDistinguisher>).as[Long]
)
```

The problem is, I cannot create a UDF from `chooseDistinguisher`, because `countDistinct` accepts a `Column`, and to turn a UDF into a `Column` you need to specify the *input* column names, which I cannot do - I do not know which name to use for the "values" of a `KeyValueGroupedDataset`.

I think it should be possible, because `KeyValueGroupedDataset` itself does something similar:

```
def count(): Dataset[(K, Long)] = agg(functions.count("*").as(ExpressionEncoder[Long]()))
```

However, this method cheats a bit because it uses `"*"` as the column name, but I need to specify a particular column (i.e. the column of the "value" in a key-value grouped dataset). Also, when you use typed functions from the `typed` object, you also do not need to specify the column name, and it works somehow.

So, is it possible to do this, and if it is, how to do it?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a job for a macro, though mixing `DataFrames` and static typing will bring you only troubles. Alternatively don't use SQL at all, and go with [`Aggregator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101530/1560062).

Comment: The thing is, I would like to avoid reimplementing all of the aggregation functions which are already there, so I don't want to create custom aggregators. As for mixing dataframes and static typing, well, in spark 2.0 DataFrame is just an alias to `Dataset[Row]`, so I would expect that everything which works for dataframes should equally work for datasets, as long as proper type information is provided.

Comment: This is why I thought about macros. Regarding your expectations - `DataFrame` is a specific case of `Dataset`, and majority of the `DataFrame` optimizations, don't apply to `Dataset` in general. Frameless provides a bit more sane approach to the API, but still far aways in terms of optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

As I know it's not possible with `agg` transformation, which expects `TypedColumn` type which is constructed based on `Column` type using `as` method, so you need to start from not type-safe expression. If somebody knows solution I would be interested to see it...

If you need to use type-safe aggregation you can use one of below approaches:

- `mapGroups` - where you can implement Scala function responsible for aggregating `Iterator`
- implement your custom `Aggregator` as suggested above

First approach needs less code, so below I'm showing quick example:

```
def countDistinct[T](values: Iterator[T])(chooseDistinguisher: T => String): Long =
     values.map(chooseDistinguisher).toSeq.distinct.size

ds
   .groupByKey(s => Key(s.x, s.y))
   .mapGroups((k,vs) => (k, countDistinct(vs)(_.name)))
```

In my opinion Spark Dataset type-safe API is still much less mature than not type safe DataFrame API. Some time ago I was thinking that it could be good idea to implement simple to use type-safe aggregation API for Spark Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this use case is better handled with `DataFrame`, which you can later convert back into a `Dataset[A]`.

```
// Code assumes SQLContext implicits are present
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}

val colName = "id"
ds.toDF
  .withColumn("key", f.concat('x, f.lit(":"), 'y))
  .groupBy('key)
  .agg(countDistinct(f.col(colName)).as("cntd"))
```