# Stateful aggregation function in PySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

From PySpark, I am trying to define a custom aggregator **that is accumulating state** . Is it possible in Spark 2.3 ?

AFAIK, it is now possible to define a custom UDAF in PySpark since Spark 2.3 (cf [How to define and use a User-Defined Aggregate Function in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100973/how-to-define-and-use-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-spark-sql)), by calling `pandas_udf` with the `PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG` keyword. However given that it is just taking a function as a parameter I don't think it is possible to carry state around during the aggregation.

From Scala, I see it is possible to have stateful aggregation by either extending `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` or `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator` , but is there a similar thing I can do on python-side only?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the python syntax by isn't flatMapGroupWithState available in pyspark ?

Comment: seems like it isn't !

Comment: and you want everything in python ?

Comment: so far it is the goal :)

Comment: Looking into this more it seems that new in 2.3 is the ability to call a scala/java UDAF from python.   [SPARK-19439](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19439)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators).

You could leverage spark streaming built-in [state management](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#arbitrary-stateful-operations).

simple accumulator example for use in SQL

```
from  pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

# have some data
df = spark.range(10).toDF("num")

# have a table
df.createOrReplaceTempView("num_table")

# have an accumulator
accSum = sc.accumulator(0)

# have a function that accumulates
def add_acc(int_val):
  accSum.add(int_val)
  return int_val

# register function as udf
spark.udf.register("reg_addacc", add_acc, IntegerType())

# use in sql
spark.sql("SELECT sum(reg_addacc(num)) FROM num_table").show()

# get value from accumulator
print(accSum.value)
```

45

Comment: but it seems they are not available through spark-sql right?
accumulators seem to be for regular spark tasks
"state management" part seems to refer to spark streaming

Comment: I am sure I have seen a udf that manages state in an accumulator that can be called from sql.  However, I can't find it right now.  I'll have to try it out.

Comment: updated answer with accumulator / udf / sql example.