# How to combine/chain sql functions with UDAFs in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use a bunch of predefined sql functions along with my own UDAF on a Spark dataframe in PySpark

```
    @F.udf
    def mode(v):
     from collections import Counter
     x = [w[0] for w in Counter(v).most_common(5)]
     return x

   funs = [mean, max, min, stddev, approxCountDistinct, mode]
   columns = df.columns
   expr = [f(col(c)) for f in funs for c in columns]

   s = df.agg(*expr).collect()
```

When I try to use my udf along with other functions I get:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty. Wrap '(avg(CAST(`DBN` AS DOUBLE)) AS `avg(DBN)` in windowing function(s) or wrap '`DBN`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;

But when I run:

```
funs = [mode]
   columns = df.columns
   expr = [f(collect_list(col(c))) for f in funs for c in columns]

   s = df.agg(*expr).collect()
```

It gives the correct results but only for my UDF and not the other functions.

Is there a way I can combine the collect_list function into my udf so that I can run my udf along with other functions.

Comment: Which is your UDF? `mode`? I am seeing that `funs = [mode]` has only your UDF, so it will return values only for UDF

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are using udf in aggregate funtion where you should be using UDAF.
1. You can either define your own UDAF by following [How to define and use a User-Defined Aggregate Function in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100973/how-to-define-and-use-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-spark-sql), or
2. You could do aggregation manually and then pass to your udf. As you want to use collect_list before calling your udf, you can do something like:

```
@F.udf
    def mode(v):
     from collections import Counter
     x = [w[0] for w in Counter(v).most_common(5)]
     return x

funs = [mean, max, min, stddev, approxCountDistinct, mode]
my_funs = [mode]
expr = [f(collect_list(col(c))) if f in my_funs  else f(col(c)) for f in funs for c in columns]
s = df.agg(*expr).collect()
```

In the above code, collect_list is used to do aggregation before calling udf on the column.