# pySpark sequential window function / access previously computed valued (previous row)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pySpark dataframe and need to compute a column which depends on the value of the same column in the previous row. But instead of using the *old* value of this column of the previous row, I need the *new* one, to which the calculation was already applied.

Specifically, I need to compute the following: Given a dataframe with a column `A` in a specific order `order`. Compute a column `B` sequentially as `B = MAX(0, LAG(B) - LAG(A))`, starting with a default value of `0` for the first row.

Example:

```
Input:
order | A  
------|----
  0   | -1
  1   | -2
  2   |  4
  3   |  4
  4   | -1
  5   |  4
  6   | -1

Wanted output:
order | A  | B
------|----|---
  0   | -1 | 0 <- B here is here set to 0
  1   | -2 | 1 
  2   |  4 | 3
  3   |  4 | 0
  4   | -1 | 0
  5   |  4 | 1
  6   | -1 | 0
```

Using the default `F.lag` window function does not work, since this one yields only the *old* previous row, since otherwise distributed computing is no longer possible, if it needs to be computed sequentially.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850077/calculating-column-value-in-current-row-of-spark-dataframe-based-on-the-calculat/70850969#70850969) might help

Comment: Looks like what I am searching for, thanks! But the computation has a lot of redundancy in it and turns from a linear runtime into a quadratic one, which might be a problem for big dataframes.